# LinearLayout position three buttons with the same padding between them

Tags: java, android

I'd like to position three Floating action buttons in the line with the same padding. The result should look like this. [How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByPu4.jpg) (It's from iOS Google Translate app)

But right now it looks like this: [How it look right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLLGv.jpg) (That middle capture FAB will be invisible).

Here is my layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutCamera2">

        <TextureView
            android:id="@+id/textureView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/baseline"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:background="@color/strapGrey">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/browseImagesFAB"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_library_white_24dp"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/strapGrey"
                app:fabSize="mini"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/captureInvisible"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_white_24dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/strapGrey" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/flashFAB"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_flash_off_white_24dp"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/strapGrey"
                app:fabSize="mini"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/captureImageFAB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_white_24dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've tried setting up android:layout_weight as you can see there but it just doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: Short answer is that `FloatingActionButton` doesn't play nice with the LinearLayout. Try using `CircleImageView` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple example to implementing your design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_height"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#757575"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_nav_voucher"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/nav_center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_other"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_nav_other"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the result should look like this
[image]

Comment: Can I ask what's the value of @dimen/bottom_nav_height?

Comment: Ah. Just the default height of bottom navigation:56dp. Change it to 56dp or any value you want

Comment: One more question. What's that View object supposed to be if the first LinearLayout is basically the navigation bar where those two ImageViews are?

Comment: It's just the fake view to guarantee that the parent view contains 3 views which have the same width.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.vzw.www.myapplication.MainActivity"
android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

This will make this>

[image]

Also, they dont have to be BUTTONS. You can do the same thing with ImageViews or TextViews.